# Replace String in Bidimensional array

Tags: javascript

I scrape a webpage that it has a table. I returned the array like this:

```
[
  [
    'Veículo',
    'Entrega\nSem/Com oco\nQtde',
    'Entrega\nSem/Com oco\nKg',
    'Com oco Kg\n%'
  ],
  [
    'AAA3B43',
    '0 / 29',
    '0 / 1.712',
    '100\n100\n100\n '
  ],
  [
    'BBB8922',
    '0 / 22',
    '0 / 1.170',
    '100\n100\n100\n '
  ]
];
```

My array is bigger than this and it have a lot of columns, with empty fields. I posted just the necessary.

Then, I would like to return the same data but replacing ***\n*** by ***|*** to save in a text file and proccess this after that.

I tried the code below but this not working.

```
var oldArray = [
  [
    'Veículo',
    'Entrega\nSem/Com oco\nQtde',
    'Entrega\nSem/Com oco\nKg',
    'Com oco Kg\n%'
  ],
  [
    'AAA3B43',
    '0 / 29',
    '0 / 1.712',
    '100\n100\n100\n '
  ],
  [
    'BBB8922',
    '0 / 22',
    '0 / 1.170',
    '100\n100\n100\n '
  ]
];

var newArray = new Array;

oldArray.forEach((lines, index) => {
  lines.forEach((childLines, childIndex) => {
    newArray.push(lines.map(function(item){
      return item.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,'|');
    }));
  });
  
});

console.log(newArray);
```

May anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already looping over the strings in your inner array with the inner `.forEach()` loop, so there is no need too perform another iteration over these with `.map()`, instead, you can update your `.push()` method to just push the update string value:

```
newArray.push(childLines.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,'|'));
```

Your callbacks also don't need to accept index arguments if you never use them, passing just the element will work also:

```js
var oldArray = [[ 'Veículo', 'Entrega\nSem/Com oco\nQtde', 'Entrega\nSem/Com oco\nKg', 'Com oco Kg\n%' ], [ 'BTT3B43', '0 / 29', '0 / 1.712', '100\n100\n100\n ' ], [ 'EKV8922', '0 / 22', '0 / 1.170', '100\n100\n100\n ' ]];

var newArray = [];
oldArray.forEach(lines => {
  lines.forEach(childLines => {
    newArray.push(childLines.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,'|'));
  });
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Or, if you prefer, you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which might be more suitable since you want to create a new array of mapped values:

```js
const oldArray = [[ 'Veículo', 'Entrega\nSem/Com oco\nQtde', 'Entrega\nSem/Com oco\nKg', 'Com oco Kg\n%' ], [ 'BTT3B43', '0 / 29', '0 / 1.712', '100\n100\n100\n ' ], [ 'EKV8922', '0 / 22', '0 / 1.170', '100\n100\n100\n ' ]];

const newArray = oldArray.map(
  lines => lines.map(childLines => childLines.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g,'|'))
);

console.log(newArray);
```